# what technology & architecture to choose for a display board

Tags: design-patterns, gwt, architecture

His to everyone,

I have actually 2 questions in one :) I am about to start into a new project, which is basically a display board (similar to what you see in airports or stock exchanges but for another purpose). It should have many text items, price tags, and buttons for selection. The whole thing should run in a browser and reflect real-time changes (such as frequent updates of prices, and rearrangement of items).

**Technology**

First choice of technology that comes to mind is GWT that helps to keep traffic low and allows for targeted updates of display areas (since rendering happens on the client side). Based on my experience, there are some cons with this choice however: porting HTML and CSS from static layouts is much more time-consuming in GWT since you only see generated HTML at runtime (UiBinder makes is somewhat more convenient, but the problem at large remains), DevMode is excruciatingly slow under Linux and compiling a permutations for a single deploy can take minutes. Which all contributes to much slower development times than with say JSP or JSF.

Is there some other technology or approach that is very low-key in terms of traffic and is able to display data changing in a real time? We obviously don't want to save the whole new page if some price tag changes its value or position on the display. And faster development times would be a treat :)

**Architecture**

What would be an appropriate pattern to adopt for this case. I've tried having an index object that would contain references to other price and item objects. So that if arrangement of price tags changes on the screen, new ones arrive, old ones get updated a new index object is created and sent to the client. The client knows than that the display should be updated and renders it anew. The positive thing is that it gives you many reusable components (price and item object), on the negative side though is that this rerendering of the whole screen, if a new item is added, is becomes CPU intensive as more updates come. There is also no one-to-one correspondence between index object and layout of the page: so if you designer has chosen a table-based layout and there is one empty row between item 1 and item 2 then you cannot map index position of the item object to its position on the owning table without some additional processing.

I will be watching shortly the event bus pattern presented in one of the Google videos on GWT. Have a feeling that this might also give a guidance on the right path.

Many thanks for your suggestions!

Update: wording & style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DevMode is excruciatingly slow under Linux

There have been several people with DevMode performance problems lately, and I'm really not sure, why that is. In my experience, especially on Linux, DevMode is very quick (in fact, I'm mostly using Mac currently, and it's a lot slower there.) Just to give you a comparable figure: Reloading the official StockWatcher tutorial after making a code change takes about *one second* on my Linux machine. Even with my largest project, which uses an almost extreme amount of widgets on one page, reload times are still very good.

I would be really interested, in which cases you see slowness: When reloading the page in the browser, when restarting the server (almost always unnecessary, by the way), when redeploying the server side (can be done very quickly, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557342/gwt-force-update-on-server-during-development-mode/4562176#4562176))? One thing I'd definitely recommend, is to use the original Sun/Oracle JVM instead of GCJ (which is often the default on Linux.) Also experiment with different browsers.

> Is there some other technology or approach that is very low-key in terms of traffic and is able to display data changing in a real time?

Yes, anything that uses AJAX, and JSON to transfer the data.

> What would be an appropriate pattern to adopt for this case.

Actually, the official StockWatcher tutorial should be relatively similar to what you want to do, i.e. it mostly *displays* frequently updated data. If your updates arrive irregularly, you may want to consider using Comet to reduce the number of requests, but I'd start out with frequent polling (like StockWatcher), and fine-tune later.

> rerendering of the whole screen, if a new item is added, is becomes CPU intensive as more updates come.

UiBinder uses innerHTML instead of DOM operations to modify the UI, and it combines that with browser-specific optimizations - so it's probably as fast as it gets. If the performance of these updates is a concern of yours, then GWT is really a very good choice.
A few additional pointers that may help if your UI actually gets slow can be found in ["What should I do to speed up a slow GWT app using MVC"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304934/what-should-i-do-to-speed-up-a-slow-gwt-app-using-mvc/4305678#4305678).

> you cannot map index position of the item object to its position on the owning table without some additional processing.

This depends on the model you're using. Maybe design a widget (e.g. MyTable.ui.xml) together with your designer, and then implement the according logic in your Java classes (doesn't have to be directly in MyTable.java, if complex mapping is required). <sub>If you need a solution for a specific problem with that mapping, it would probably be best to open a separate question.</sub>

Comment: I tried starting Firefox in DevMode on a faster machine (more memory) and it really is faster. I think it really has to do with main memory then. However, if I start DevMode in debug mode, its awefully slow again (barely usable). Do you have an idea as to a probable cause? We dont use external server (jboss). DevMode in Chrome is even worse.

Comment: @d56: I've experienced one circumstance, under which DevMode gets *really* slow (hardly usable), and that's when the code server and the browser are on a different machine. DevMode needs lots of communication between the code server and the browser plugin. It's theoretically possible, that this turns into a problem even when they're on the same machine, e.g: When the network routing or iptables are messed up, when performing intensive packet analysis, ...